# Angular app with only a CSS file VS each component with its CSS file

Tags: html, css, angular

As my Angular 2/4 app is growing more and more I have more than a hundred components, and each component has its CSS file.

**Do you think it would be better to declare a CSS file in index.html and have all my styles there?** 
As I could apply specific CSS rules to a component by referencing its selector...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS/SCSS/LESS-Files (depending on what you use) in default follow some convention, starting with your `src/styles.css` in the root of your Source-Folder.
In the `src/app/app.component.css` you'll dive on step "deeper". Finally you got the CSS-Files for each of your components.

I think it is meant to be like that:
Global styles, that apply to all of your Applications-Styles (like html and body style-definitions) should be declared in the `src/styles.css`. A bit more app specific, yet global styles for the Angular-App itself should be declared in `src/app/app.component.css`.

Specific Definitions that apply only to a single component should be declared directly in the components css-file.

This way you can keep your CSS organized and follow along the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) rule :)

regards

Answer (score 0):

imo you should have separate css files for each component but also one global css file for shared styles

Answer (score 0):

Having separate file for each component is a very good idea. 
To maintain a scalable project with nice and clean CSS architecture I would recommend something like ITCSS
https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/

Consider using preprocessor such as SASS and LESS if u are not using them yet.